# Using Blazor Virtualize component under Select or InputSelect for options

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use Blazor Virtualize component in a **select** or **inputSelect** element for options. It doesn't render anything.

```
<select @bind="selectedItem"
    <Virtualize Items="itemsList" Context="itemC">
        <option value="@itemC.code"> @itemC.name</option>
    </Virtualize>
</select>
```

I have about 5000 items in the dropdown which slows down the application, that's why trying to enable virtual scrolling.

Comment: As you ask on github, it is not supported (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29087)

Comment: It was answered(that it is not supported) on github after posting here.